# Stripe Subscription with SetupIntent the 3DS is asked twice

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to set up a subscription for a price of more than 100€ with stripe. Stripe asks me twice for 3DS.

Step 1 : i create a new customer

```
Customer customer = Customer.create(customerCreateParams)
```

Step 2 : i create a setupintent

```
        SetupIntentCreateParams setupIntentCreateParams =
            SetupIntentCreateParams
                    .builder()
                    .setCustomer(customer.getId())
                    .addPaymentMethodType("card")
                    .build();

    SetupIntent.create(setupIntentCreateParams)
```

Step 3 : With stripe JS i collect the card and confirm the setupintent with clientsecret:

```
            const options = {
            clientSecret: 'seti_foo_secret_bar'

      const elements = stripe.elements(options);

       stripe.confirmSetup({
          elements,
```

Step 4 : I use this stipe card with mandatory 3DS : 4000000000003220

then Stripe JS, request the 3DS, then i confirm 3DS and everything works fine for now

Step 5 : I put the setupintent payment method as default payment method to the customer

```
        Customer customer = Customer.retrieve(setupIntent.getCustomer());

    Map<String, Object> payCus = new HashMap<>();
    payCus.put("default_payment_method", setupIntent.getPaymentMethod());

    Map<String, Object> cusParams = new HashMap<>();
    cusParams.put("invoice_settings", payCus);
    customer.update(cusParams);
```

Step 6 : I create a subscription with a price already created via stripe dashboard

```
    List<Object> items = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> itemParam = new HashMap<>();
    itemParam.put(
            "price",
            "price_foobar"
    );
    items.add(itemParam);
    Map<String, Object> subParams = new HashMap<>();
    subParams.put("customer", setupIntent.getCustomer());
    subParams.put("items", items);
    Subscription.create(subParams);
```

Step 7 : the subscription payment is incomplet, because 3DS is asked again
[image]

Can someone help me with that ?
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a card that always requires 3DS verification, you need to redirect the user to confirm his card always.

First of all, you should follow this guide for creating subscription, not by using SetupIntent
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements

In order to test, you should use this card(4000002500003155) that requires 3DS unless setup
https://support.stripe.com/questions/test-card-requiring-3d-secure-authentication-for-every-transaction

In case you have a user that has a card that requires always 3ds (like the *3220 one you are using in your test) you need to ask the user to complete the payment each renewal of the subscription

You can refer to the `next_action` in the related subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent, it contains the hooks for the 3ds redirect confirmation
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-next_action-use_stripe_sdk